# removeObject from array based on index

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray, plist, nsindexpath

Hi I have one viewController with a IBAction that adds a string to a Plist NSMutableArray.

This Plist is then read into another viewController which is a tableView. This string from the Plist array populates a textField in a custom cell with the String "1" (without quotes). This is basically a basket system where the users adds a product to the basket in this case adds the 1 string to a qty array which populates the qty textfield. These qty textfields are added dynamically to the basket view so on many occasions I would have many rows that contain the textfield with the string "1" inside them.

Now the problem I have is that when the button to add a product to the basket is pressed I have another button on the alertView to remove the product from the plist. The issue is I add the the string like this

```
NSString *string = @"1";

    [enteredQty2 addObject:string];
    NSArray *paths4 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory4 = [paths4 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path4 = [documentsDirectory4 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"qty.plist"];
    [enteredQty2 writeToFile:path4 atomically:YES];
```

and remove the string like this

```
NSString *string = @"1";

    [enteredQty2 removeObject:string];
    NSArray *paths4 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory4 = [paths4 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path4 = [documentsDirectory4 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"qty.plist"];
    [enteredQty2 writeToFile:path4 atomically:YES];
```

The issue I have is that if I have several items added to the basket they all initially have the qty string as "1". So what happens when I remove the object it removes the "1" from all the qtyTextFields not just the selected product in question. And of course the QtyTextFields change based on the QTY a user wants so removing "1" from the array with lets say the QTY "12" will have no effect.

I am not sure what the best approach is should I somehow tag the string "1" when I add it and remove the item using selected tag. Of course these tags would have to be dynamic and unique?

Any help really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your array should probably contain `NSDictionary` objects instead of `NSString`. Perhaps something like below?

```
NSDictionary *item = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"quantity",
                                            @"yourUniqueProductId", @"id",
                                            @"My Cool Product", @"title", nil];
```

Then you could add that item to the array:

```
[enteredQty2 addObject:item];
```

To delete an item, you could loop through the array:

```
for (NSDictionary *item in enteredQty2) {
        if ([[item objectForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString:@"yourUniqueProductId"]) {
                [enteredQty2 removeObject:item];
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply when I click the button it crashes the app the log just says [__NSCFDictionary intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa170310'

Comment: That code is definitely just an example and will need tweaking for your specific purpose. But which button is giving an error? To add an item or remove?

Comment: Hi @Josh its adding the item thats crashing. If I check the plist its created the dict and the keys but crashes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure what's happening there. Can you set a breakpoint in your code, and step through to tell me exactly which line causes the crash?

Comment: sorry josh it was a part of my code that was crashing it. The only issue I still have is this I only add the NSnumber 1 and key quantity to the dict. Now when I come to deleting it in the for loop how do I identify each of the 1's for each of the textFields. i.e if objectForKey = @"quantity" it removes all NSnumber 1's how would I identify which one I want to remove? And of course the user may have changed the quantity number to any number not just 1

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've run into an issue where NSString caches very short identical strings, and will return the same object even though you create it twice.  Then, when you call removeObject, it finds multiple copies of the same object so removes them all.

This should work for you:

```
// Returns the lowest index whose corresponding array value is equal to a given object
NSInteger index = [enteredQty2 indexOfObject:string];

// delete the object at index
if (index != NSNotFound) {
    [enteredQty2 removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
```